# Finidng ranges of values (5 points) across ranges of time (1 hr)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm monitoring the effectiveness of a temperature controller in an IoT application.  I'm trying to find "interesting points" in the time series. These are similar to local minima or maxima but include points on the curve when a trend is beginning.  It's not just min and max. It's where a range of 5 points occurred within an hour.

Source

```
| inMins | unixTime         | temp |  
|--------|------------------|------|   
| 0      | 1479042000000000 | 10.0 |  
| 5      | 1479042300000000 | 11.0 |  
| 10     | 1479042600000000 | 12.0 |  
| 15     | 1479042600000000 | 13.0 |  
| 20     | 1479043200000000 | 14.0 |  
| 25     | 1479043500000000 | 15.0 |  
| 30     | 1479043800000000 | 14.0 |  
| 35     | 1479044100000000 | 13.0 |  
| 40     | 1479044400000000 | 12.0 |  
| 45     | 1479044700000000 | 11.0 |  
| 50     | 1479045000000000 | 10.0 |  
| 55     | 1479045300000000 | 9.0  |  
| 60     | 1479045600000000 | 8.0  |  
| 65     | 1479045900000000 | 9.0  |  
| 70     | 1479046200000000 | 10.0 |  
| 75     | 1479046500000000 | 11.0 |  
| 80     | 1479046800000000 | 12.0 |  
| 85     | 1479047100000000 | 13.0 |  
| 90     | 1479047400000000 | 14.0 |
```

Desired Shape

```
| inMins | unixTime         | temp | coldOrHot |  
|--------|------------------|------|-----------|  
| 0      | 1479042000000000 | 10.0 | 1         |  
| 25     | 1479043500000000 | 15.0 | 2         |  
| 30     | 1479043800000000 | 14.0 | 2         |
| 35     | 1479044100000000 | 13.0 | 2         |  
| 60     | 1479045600000000 | 8.0  | 1         |  
| 65     | 1479045900000000 | 9.0  | 1         |
```

My current results have some problems

```
| inMins | unixTime         | temp | coldOrHot |  
|--------|------------------|------|-----------|  
| 25     | 1479043500000000 | 15.0 | 2         |  
| 30     | 1479043800000000 | 14.0 | 2         |  
| 60     | 1479045600000000 | 8.0  | 1         |  
| 65     | 1479045900000000 | 9.0  | 1         |  
| 70     | 1479046200000000 | 10.0 | 1         |  
| 75     | 1479046500000000 | 11.0 | 1         |  
| 80     | 1479046800000000 | 12.0 | 1         |  
| 85     | 1479047100000000 | 13.0 | 1         |  
| 90     | 1479047400000000 | 14.0 | 1         |
```

SQL

```
Select 
  inMins,
  unixTime,
  temp,
  coldOrHot
from 
(Select
  inMins,
  unixTime,
  temp,
  -- 1 means Cold, 2 means Hot, 0 is noise
  if(temp=theLowInWindowDesc,1,
  if(temp=theHighInWindowDesc,2,0)) as coldOrHot,
  theHighInWindowDesc,
  theLowInWindowDesc
FROM
  (SELECT
  inMins,
  unixTime,
  temp,
  theHighInWindowDesc,
  theLowInWindowDesc
  FROM
    (Select
        inMins,
        unixTime,
        temp,
        MAX(temp) OVER(ORDER BY
          unixTime desc RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING
          AND CURRENT ROW) AS theHighInWindowDesc,
        MIN(temp) OVER(ORDER BY
         unixTime desc RANGE BETWEEN 60 * 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING
         AND CURRENT ROW) AS theLowInWindowDesc
        FROM
        [esheetzbq:findingLocalExtrema.timeSeriesForKevin]
        ORDER BY
        inMins asc
     )
  )
)
where coldOrHot=1 or coldOrHot=2
```

Problems

1. I'm not picking up the "cold" at minute 0 when temp was 10 and increased by 5 points within 25 mins
2. I'm not picking up the "hot" value at minute 35.
3. The results from mins 70 to 90 don't take into account my range criteria of 5 points and is occurring because my current logic is based on extremes not ranges.  The SQL windowing function of ""OVER"" picks up less than an hour's worth of rows in the final hour of the data set. This is expected behavior, and I'm uncertain what logic is best used to exclude records that give warnings without seeing a range of 5 points.
4. Will this scale?  I'll be running this logic over a record set of about 34M rows.

Comment: I don't get what the "5 points in an hour" has to do with this.  It looks like you are just looking for points that are monotonic.

Comment: can you explain why inMins=30 is in your output?

Comment: you should clarify your logic  - otherwise it is shot in the air for any of us who really want to help you with your challenge

Comment: Sounds like my question could have been written beter.  Let me see if this helps to clarify.  inMins=30 qualifies because temperature continued another 5 points down before reversing.  So, it's not just the min and max within a time range but the points where temperature moved by a range of 5 points.  From min 25 to 50 temp moved 5 points down, and from mins 30 to 55, temp also moved 5 points down.  I've been asked to do more than just find the local minima and maxima, but also find the points on the trend that match the range criteria.

Comment: so, based on what I hear so far, I would expect also to see inMins=35, 40, etc as they are also within the 5 point trend! yet, they are not in your desired output. so it means that there is something els ein your mind that you are missing to describe in your logic

Comment: Mikhail, that's correct for min 35. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.  I'll modify my question with the correct desired output. min 40 does not qualify because the low temperature of 8 is < than 5 points away from the temperature at min 40.

Comment: i think i got it now - at least it will be easier for someone else now to help you. but i will also try little later when have few spare minutes :o)

Comment: Gordon, the folks looking at the data care about the range of the temperature change and the volatility of that change. A change of only 2 or 3 points over an hour is not as concerning as a change of 5 or more points. Thanks for showing interest!

Comment: your example has all ups and downs within the hour so it is not clear what to do if up sequence (or down) spans two or more hours. can you extend your example respectively? and it has not just 5 points but let's say 15 points range. what the logic to apply to deal with this

Comment: Cool question!  Let’s say the temperature continued to rise at the pace of 1 degree every 5 minutes for an additional 2 hours.  It rose from 14 degrees at min 90 up to 37 at min 210.  I want to put a 1 in the coldOrHot column for each of the 5 min increments between 95 and 185 but not at mins 190 through 210.  That’s because a 1, is not actually an indicator of cold.  It’s an indicator that the temp got another 5 points higher than the current temp within the hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL
I havent done any attempts to improve/optimize query - rather purposely kept it "broken" to subqueries exactly the way i wrote them - to make sure the logic is easily traced and thus understood
I have included below data for easy testing but you can comment out data portion if you want to test it on real data

Have fun :o)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `esheetzbq.findingLocalExtrema.timeSeriesForKevin` AS (
  SELECT 0 AS inMins, 1479042000000000 AS unixTime, 10.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 5 AS inMins, 1479042300000000 AS unixTime, 11.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 10 AS inMins, 1479042600000000 AS unixTime, 12.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 15 AS inMins, 1479042900000000 AS unixTime, 13.0 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 20 AS inMins, 1479043200000000 AS unixTime, 14.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 25 AS inMins, 1479043500000000 AS unixTime, 15.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 30 AS inMins, 1479043800000000 AS unixTime, 14.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 35 AS inMins, 1479044100000000 AS unixTime, 13.0 AS temp UNION ALL
  SELECT 40 AS inMins, 1479044400000000 AS unixTime, 12.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 45 AS inMins, 1479044700000000 AS unixTime, 11.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 50 AS inMins, 1479045000000000 AS unixTime, 10.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 55 AS inMins, 1479045300000000 AS unixTime, 9.0 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 60 AS inMins, 1479045600000000 AS unixTime, 8.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 65 AS inMins, 1479045900000000 AS unixTime, 9.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 70 AS inMins, 1479046200000000 AS unixTime, 10.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 75 AS inMins, 1479046500000000 AS unixTime, 11.0 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 80 AS inMins, 1479046800000000 AS unixTime, 12.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 85 AS inMins, 1479047100000000 AS unixTime, 13.0 AS temp UNION ALL   SELECT 90 AS inMins, 1479047400000000 AS unixTime, 14.0 AS temp UNION ALL        SELECT 95 AS inMins, 1479047700000000 AS unixTime, 15 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS inMins, 1479048000000000 AS unixTime, 16 AS temp UNION ALL  SELECT 105 AS inMins, 1479048300000000 AS unixTime, 17 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 110 AS inMins, 1479048600000000 AS unixTime, 18 AS temp UNION ALL 
  SELECT 115 AS inMins, 1479048900000000 AS unixTime, 19 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 120 AS inMins, 1479049200000000 AS unixTime, 20 AS temp UNION ALL      SELECT 125 AS inMins, 1479049500000000 AS unixTime, 21 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 130 AS inMins, 1479049800000000 AS unixTime, 22 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 135 AS inMins, 1479050100000000 AS unixTime, 23 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 140 AS inMins, 1479050400000000 AS unixTime, 24 AS temp UNION ALL      SELECT 145 AS inMins, 1479050700000000 AS unixTime, 25 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 150 AS inMins, 1479051000000000 AS unixTime, 26 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 155 AS inMins, 1479051300000000 AS unixTime, 27 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 160 AS inMins, 1479051600000000 AS unixTime, 28 AS temp UNION ALL      SELECT 165 AS inMins, 1479051900000000 AS unixTime, 29 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 170 AS inMins, 1479052200000000 AS unixTime, 30 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 175 AS inMins, 1479052500000000 AS unixTime, 31 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 180 AS inMins, 1479052800000000 AS unixTime, 32 AS temp UNION ALL      SELECT 185 AS inMins, 1479053100000000 AS unixTime, 33 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 190 AS inMins, 1479053400000000 AS unixTime, 34 AS temp UNION ALL       SELECT 195 AS inMins, 1479053700000000 AS unixTime, 35 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 200 AS inMins, 1479054000000000 AS unixTime, 36 AS temp UNION ALL      SELECT 205 AS inMins, 1479054300000000 AS unixTime, 37 AS temp UNION ALL SELECT 210 AS inMins, 1479054600000000 AS unixTime, 38 AS temp  
), y AS (
  SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp, delta,
    IFNULL(SUM(new_group_flag) OVER(ORDER BY unixTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp,
      LEAD(temp) OVER(ORDER BY unixTime) - temp AS delta,
      CAST(SIGN(LEAD(temp) OVER(ORDER BY unixTime) - temp) != IFNULL(SIGN(temp - LAG(temp) OVER(ORDER BY unixTime)), SIGN(LEAD(temp) OVER(ORDER BY unixTime) - temp)) AS INT64) AS new_group_flag
    FROM `esheetzbq.findingLocalExtrema.timeSeriesForKevin`
  )
), yy AS (
  SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp, delta, grp FROM y UNION ALL
  SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp, delta, grp + 1 AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp, delta, grp, 
      unixTime - MAX(unixTime) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY unixTime DESC) AS qq
    FROM y
  ) WHERE qq = 0
), v AS (
  SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp, delta,
     MIN(temp) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY unixTime RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3600000000 FOLLOWING) AS min_temp,
     MAX(temp) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY unixTime RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3600000000 FOLLOWING) AS max_temp
  FROM yy
)
SELECT inMins, unixTime, temp, IF(delta=1, 1, 2) AS coldOrHot
FROM v
WHERE  ABS(max_temp - temp) >= 5 OR ABS(min_temp - temp) >= 5
```

In case you will go this direction check also [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) for more details if needed

Comment: Brilliant!  Works perfectly.  I'm grateful. Thanks.

Comment: An observation… I experimented with measures that were fractions of 1, and I received hot measures when I was expecting cold.  For example, at Mins 5, if I change the value from 11 to 10.1, then the solution generates coldOrHot to be a 2 at Mins 0 rather than 1. Changing the final if statement to evaluate for Delta >=0 rather than =1 seems to fix this.  I confess, I’m not quite understanding the logic of Delta so I’m not confident in my adjustment.  Any thoughts are appreciated.  I’m much further ahead thanks to your help.

Comment: that was my mistake. delta>=0 should be used. the "role" of delta is to see direction of change (up or down). while writing query i was fixed on your particular example when change is exactly 1.0 which is obviously not a case for real data. so your fix is correct from what I can see

Comment: Mikhail, would you mind elaborating on the usefulness of the incrementing groups? (grp) and (grp +1)?  I ran a test over 33k records where I knew the temp moved by more than 6 degrees within 30 minutes.  I did not get the signals I expected so I'm trying to discover the flaw in my logic.  For grins I did Select count(distinct grp) asNumOfGroups from y and discovered that we had over 2,000 groups.

Comment: grp allows to identify sequence of points with the same change direction. grp+1 is a trick that takes local extreme (min or max) from previous group (grp) and adds it as a starting point to next group - so that local extreme kind of gets doubled - hope this helps :o)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, helpful.  I need to look a little closer to figure out why the  behavior is different than I'd expect.  I'm wondering if it's because multiple temp recordings have the same unixTime time stamp. I previously thought this column would be "unique enough", but now I'm wondering if it's messing up the groupings which in turn is messing up the local minima/maxima.